# WildFly/JBoss server group deployment understanding

Tags: java, deployment, jboss

According to JBoss documentation:

> In managed domain deployments are associated with a server group.
>   Deployments will be provided to any server that belongs to a
>   particular group.

...the multiple servers in common server group become the single one virtually.

But how does JBoss choose the target actual server for deployment?

For example, i have two different vps servers with JBoss running, which are combined to the single `main-server-group`. Then which vps server will actually host the application by following command?

> [domain@localhost:9999 /] deploy ~/Desktop/test-application.war --server-group=main-server-group
>   'test-application.war' deployed successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application will be deployed to both servers.

If you were to go to `http://server1:8080/MyApp` you should see the same as if you went to `http://server2:8080/MyApp`

The reason for this is that you would normally have a web server or proxy to load balance between the two servers. If you want to have two separate servers which **don't** have the apps deployed to each, then put them in different server groups or, a better solution would be to run JBoss in standalone mode, rather than domain mode.